# Как запустить python скрипт от имени системы Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, клиент-сервер

Есть клиент-серверное приложение, которое  должно передавать данные вне зависимости входа в учетную запись (такое реализованно в `litemanager server`). Пользователь не вошел в учетную запись, но программа уже работает и дает соединение.

Хотелось бы такое же реализовать....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что делает скрипт, вы можете:

1. упаковать его в сервис, который затем должен быть установлен
2. добавьте его в реестр Windows (HKCU \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Run)
3. добавьте к нему ярлык в папку автозагрузки меню «Пуск» - его расположение может меняться в зависимости от версии ОС, но у установщиков всегда есть инструкция по установке ярлыка в эту папку
4. используйте планировщик задач Windows, и тогда вы можете установить задачу для нескольких видов событий, включая вход в систему и запуск.

Фактическое решение зависит от ваших потребностей и от того, что на самом деле делает скрипт.

Некоторые заметки о различиях:

- Решение № 1 запускает скрипт с компьютера, а решение № 2 и № 3 запускают его, когда пользователь, установивший его, входит в систему.
- Также стоит отметить, что # 1 всегда запускает скрипт, в то время как # 2 и # 3 запускают скрипт только для определенного пользователя (я думаю, что если вы используете пользователя по умолчанию, то он будет запускаться для всех, но я не уверен в деталях).
- Решение № 2 немного более «скрыто» для пользователя, в то время как решение № 3 оставляет пользователю гораздо больше контроля в плане отключения автоматического запуска.
- Наконец, решение № 1 требует административных прав, в то время как два других могут быть выполнены любым пользователем.
- Решение № 4 - это то, что я обнаружил в последнее время, и оно очень простое. Единственная проблема, которую я заметил, состоит в том, что скрипт python вызовет появление небольшого командного окна.

Как видите, все сводится к тому, что вы хотите сделать; например, если это что-то только для ваших целей, я бы просто перетащил его в папку автозагрузки.

В любом случае, в последнее время я полагаюсь на решение № 4, как на самый быстрый и простой подход.